# Loading project information forever in SonarQube 5.4

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.4

When viewing some projects in SonarQube the project overview is not loaded.
What could be the reason for this? Shouldn't there be an error message or similar if the project is corrupt in some way?

[image: Progress indicator but nothing is loaded]

Edit: As per request, the browser error:

[image: Browser error]

Comment: Could you check browser error logs please ? If you just upgrade to v5.4, you can also try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: I'm running SonarQube 5.4 (see topic of this post).

I will try to clear the browser cache now

Comment: Clearing the cache did not help.
I've updated the post with a screenshot from the dev. options.

Comment: I was not asking the version. I wanted to know if you upgraded recently to this version.

Comment: Yes. The installation was recently updated. This error happens on both updated instances (one from 4.5.4 LTS, the other 4.5.6 LTS)

Comment: Workaround: If clicking the home (house) icon it loads correctly

Comment: Could you copy the page url here?

Comment: Interesting. The URL is: SERVER-URL//overview?id=1

(double-slash)

When removing one slash and reloading the page it works.

Comment: I didn't find any misconfiguration on the server instance, is this a known issue in SonarQube?